# Unsafe NTFS mount even with no fast restart

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, ntfs

I have disabled fast restart and still get the following message upon attempting to mount

```
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Furthermore, ntfsfix gives

```
Mounting volume... Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You either didn't disable fast boot, or you explicitly hibernated windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with "fast start", a windows thing that scrambles the hard disk apparently? But the general solution to NTFS problems is "Run chkdsk in windows", or maybe run chkdsk from a windows boot disk (should have some repair/recovery tools, maybe a windows/dos terminal somewhere) and probably like it suggests:

`Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.`

But I don't know how to do that, maybe ask Mr.Google how to work windows?

Comment: "fast boot" is a windows feature where it doesn't actually shutdown, but rather closes all applications and hibernates, so it can "start up" faster by actually resuming from hibernation.

Comment: I thought so. As to why "fast boot" would leave ntfs in "an unsafe state" is another matter, sounds more dangerous than fast, it shouldn't take more than a second or two to sync & unmount (if that's what windows calls it)

Comment: It is unsafe because it is still mounted, and you can't unmount the system volume without shutting down.

Comment: I guess my real question is then "why would windows do such a thing?" or "Why would I want to do that"? Save a few seconds? Not unmounting tends to invite data loss, not worth it imo

Comment: I ran chkdsk in windows, to no avail. I'll try it on a boot disk at when I find the time.

Comment: I concur with psusi's comment, fastboot may not really be disabled in windows. And you could double-check that you have the latest ntfs-3g installed.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, lost in delete post)

Ya fastboot and hibernation and probably Windows as well, like to know where things are.  For transfering files, I either use a USB or a separate NTFS hard disk partion (to be compatible with Windows.)

Anyone else?

Comment: It can be a good idea to keep your data separate from your OS partition, windows or linux, this seems to be another reason to do so.